# How can I run test on Hyperledger Fabric code?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

I'm sorry to interrupt you guys, but I wish to know how can I run the Hyperledger Fabric code originally.

I download all the Go, Docker, Docker composer, VSCode and those plugins for Go.
And when I using `go test consensus_test.go` in `/orderer/solo`.

It will give me these answer, so how can I run these code? Thank you.

[image]

```
$fabric@ubuntu:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/solo$ go test consensus_test.go
# command-line-arguments
./consensus_test.go:35:26: undefined: pkgLogID
./consensus_test.go:45:48: undefined: chain
./consensus_test.go:74:8: undefined: newChain
./consensus_test.go:95:11: undefined: New
./consensus_test.go:116:8: undefined: newChain
./consensus_test.go:134:8: undefined: newChain
./consensus_test.go:178:8: undefined: newChain
./consensus_test.go:220:8: undefined: newChain
./consensus_test.go:256:8: undefined: newChain
./consensus_test.go:293:8: undefined: newChain
./consensus_test.go:293:8: too many errors
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]
fabric@ubuntu:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/solo$
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved, but I don't know what happened and why.
VScode will gives a "run file test||run package test" hint on the top, I click it and it running success.